# Making one promoted link on the page bigger then the rest

Tags: 2013, javascript, web-part, css, promoted-links

I trying to have my SharePoint page appear like below using promoted links. I'm struggling everything I've tried in CSS is designing the tiles the same.[image]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Comment: SharePoint 2013 foundation.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint OOTB list webpart or creating a new custom solution using SharePoint REST APIs, HTML and CSS?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint OOTB Promoted links list and trying to use HTML and CSS.